# Disable auto completion of tag attribute value in Vue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm seeing some annoying behaviour in VS Code that I can't work out how to disable.

[image]

In this `.vue` file, I typed `<script setup lang=`. VS Code automatically added both the open and close double quotes.

If I type the complete line `<script setupe lang="ts">`, I end up with this:

[image]

How can I disable this? It does not appear to be controlled by:

- `"editor.autoClosingQuotes"` (set to `never`)
- `"html.autoClosingTags"` (`false`)
- `"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions"` (controls the bit in grey, not the double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. This is needed:

`"html.autoCreateQuotes": false`

It's part of the HTML CSS Support extension.

Comment: please search for duplicate targets before answering (and before asking).

Comment: I did. I did not find them.